# Display flex pseudo content has wrong width

Tags: css

I'm using pseudo content and a flex layout. Why does `li:before` not have the 10px width that Ive set?

https://codepen.io/adsfdsfhdsafkhdsafjkdhafskjds/pen/MWmwyOE

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Lorum 123 dfjsd 3ijfadsifj sdfjoifj oijas fdjasf ijaio</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>37dkj dfjkasdfjdsijf dksdjf jfjiasdfmdafom</p>
  </li>
</ul>

ul {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
li:before {
  content: "";
  display: flex;
  width: 10px;
  flex-basis: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By default flex items don't shrink below their minimum content size. To change this, set the item's min-width or min-height.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

by default flex is setting the shrink value to 1.
If you add `flex: 0 0 auto;` to the pseudo element your code works.

```css
ul {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
li:before {
  content: "";
  display: flex;
  width: 10px;
  flex-basis: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Lorum 123 dfjsd 3ijfadsifj sdfjoifj oijas fdjasf ijaio</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>37dkj dfjkasdfjdsijf dksdjf jfjiasdfmdafom</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
https://codepen.io/MuhammadRizwan/pen/bGWdpxB

update your class properties

```
li:before {
  content: "";
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
  min-width: 10px;
  flex-basis: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```